# Saving issue about relationship with laravel backpack

Tags: relationship, laravel-backpack, laravel-relations

I have a field in ImageCrud controller.

```
        $this->crud->addField([
            'label'     => "Etiketler",
            'type'      => 'select_multiple',
            'name'      => 'tags', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'entity'    => 'tags', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
            'model'     => "App\Models\Tag", // foreign key model
            'attribute' => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
            'pivot'     => true, 
        ]);
```

Seems like ;

[image: image crud controller select.]

Also i have 2 more models,

`Models\ImageTag.php` and `Models\Tag.php`

**ImageTag.php** ;

```
    protected $table = 'image_tags';
    protected $fillable = [
        'image_id',
        'tag_id'
    ];
```

Here is the **Tag.php** also

```
    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'description',
    ];
```

Also my **Image.php** model has tags() public function.

```
    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\ImageTag', 'id', 'image_id');
    }
```

If you keep this, CRUD controller show multiple select field. But never save image_tags tabel record.

Also here is the, request results after save button click.

[image: requests]

What should i do ? Where do i did mistake, can anyone explain this. Any idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right relation is `belongsToMany`.

here is the code,

```
    public function tags() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, ImageTag::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please let me know if after change the relation is working for you. Thanks.

Comment: hello it works great when i replace the code. The point its my migration's table name issues.  Thank you.